# Mismatch in number of elements assigned in conditional signal assignment in xilinx

Tags: syntax, vhdl, xilinx

I have an error on line 90 which is

```
90     std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)+ unsigned(b) ) when (arth_sel)="0000" else
```

and my code is :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity Arth is
    Port (signal arth_sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           c : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 downto 0);
           result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16 downto 0));
end Arth;
architecture Behavioral of Arth is
--das_result : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal a_lower :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := a(7 downto 0);
signal b_lower :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := b(7 downto 0);
signal sum_temp1_lower : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal sum_temp1_upper : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal sum_temp1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal sum_temp2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

signal daa_result: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 

begin
sum_temp1 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b));
sum_temp2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a_lower)+unsigned(b_lower));
sum_temp1_lower <= sum_temp1(7 downto 0);
sum_temp1_upper <= sum_temp1(15 downto 8);
process(a,b) 
begin
if ( unsigned(sum_temp1_upper) >9 and unsigned(sum_temp1_lower) >9) then
sum_temp1<= std_logic_vector(unsigned(sum_temp1)+66);
elsif( unsigned(sum_temp1_lower) > 9 or sum_temp2(7)='1') then
sum_temp1 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(sum_temp1)+6) ;
elsif (unsigned(sum_temp1_upper) > 9) then
sum_temp1<= std_logic_vector(unsigned(sum_temp1)+60);
end if;
daa_result<= sum_temp1;
end process;   
result <=    
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)+ unsigned(b) ) when (arth_sel)="0000" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)+ unsigned(b)) when (arth_sel)="0001" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)+ unsigned(b) + unsigned(c)) when (arth_sel)="0010" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)+1)when (arth_sel)="0011" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- unsigned(b))when (arth_sel)="0100" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- unsigned(b))when (arth_sel)="0101" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- unsigned(b) - unsigned(c))when (arth_sel)="0110" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- 1)when (arth_sel)="0111" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)* unsigned(b))when (arth_sel)="1000" else
    std_logic_vector( signed(a)* signed(b))when (arth_sel)="1001" else
    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- unsigned(b))when (arth_sel)="1010" else 

    std_logic_vector( unsigned(a)- unsigned(b))when (arth_sel)="1011" else  std_logic_vector( unsigned(not(a))+1)when (arth_sel)="1100" else
    daa_result when(arth_sel)="1101"  else 

  (others => 'X'); 

end Behavioral;
```

I really don't know what's wrong :( and I referred to this topic [vhdl: Xilinx code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351742/vhdl-xilinx-code-error) but it didn't solve my problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the selection:

```
result <=   ...
            daa_result when(arth_sel)="1101"  else
```

And one of these things is not like the other:

```
          result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16 downto 0));

signal daa_result: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

specifically, the length implied by range.

It's unclear what daa means, you can:

```
            '0'& daa_result when(arth_sel)="1101"  else
```

To increase the length to 17, matching result.

And by the way this:

```
signal a_lower :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := a(7 downto 0);
signal b_lower :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := b(7 downto 0);
```

isn't the way to assign the lower 8 bits of a and b to a_lower and b_lower respectively.  This default value assignment only has effect when the declaration of these two signals occurs, and will be all 'U's.

You can add concurrent signal assignment statements:

```
begin

    a_lower <= a(7 downto 0);
    b_lower <= b(7 downto 0);
```

(right after the architecture begin).

`c` can be declared as a non-array type:

```
    c:          in  std_logic; -- _vector (0 downto 0);
```

Requiring some VHDL legerdemain:

```
result <=    
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "0000" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "0001" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b) 
                           + unsigned'(c & "")) when arth_sel = "0010" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + 1)           when arth_sel = "0011" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "0100" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "0101" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b) 
                           - unsigned'(c & "")) when arth_sel = "0110" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - 1)           when arth_sel = "0111" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "1000" else
    std_logic_vector(signed(a)   * signed(b))   when arth_sel = "1001" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "1010" else 

    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b)) when arth_sel = "1011" else
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(not(a))+1)        when arth_sel = "1100" else
    '0' & daa_result                            when arth_sel = "1101" else
    (others => 'X');
```

Where `unsigned'(c & "")` concatenates `c` with a zero length string and qualifies the resulting array type as unsigned.